# How can I get a clip of a MongoDB stored video file？

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I've stored some video files in the database using gridfs, because the stored video is accompanied by some information (e.g., the action that the person does in this video, from a few seconds to a few seconds), and GridFs is characterized by block storage, And the data show that the stored file can be partially read without downloading the entire file, how should this video be read?
I'm sorry my English is not very good.

My code like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from gridfs import GridFS
client = MongoClient()
db = client.gridfs
fs = GridFS(db)
grid_out = fs.find({"filename": "--1DO2V4K74"})
data = grid_out[0].read()
out = open('test.mp4', 'wb')
out.write(data)
out.close()
```

I can get a whole video by this. And I want to get a part of the video.

Comment: If i were you, i would follow the manual and if there is some error, i would post here ;), https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/gridfs.html

Comment: I've tried.I see what you mean and have modified the question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should not save media(image or video) in DB, you store it in some storage drive(locally or cloud) like s3 bucket, and then store its location url in your DB. and this code might be helpful.

**or**

You can use Formidable. As It support multipart data(efficient). And for retrieve video you can use fs(file system)

Comment: Thanks. Now I am writing the GridOut instance to a temporary file, and then opening that temporary file. It would be nice to skip that extra step of writing to the file system.And how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

i have used mongo gridfs . its powerfull for store large file. read this document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/ , its very useful, i used it in spring rsocket by mongo reactive java driver